# Make `shell` command returns outdated symlink target

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, symlink

If I create a symlink pointing to a (non-existant) target, `old`.

```
ln -sf "old" /tmp/symlink
```

Then run the following Makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

all:
    @ln -sf "new" /tmp/symlink
    @ls -l /tmp/symlink
    @echo "$(shell ls -l /tmp/symlink)"
```

It outputs two different targets for the symlink:

```
lrwxrwxrwx ... /tmp/symlink -> new
lrwxrwxrwx ... /tmp/symlink -> old
```

Why does the `shell` command return an outdated target for the symlink?

Comment: Because `$(shell ...)` is evaluated before `all` is executed.

Comment: @SantoshA Why not?! First the `ls` in `$(shell)` is executed (and its result saved), then `ln`, then `ls`, then `echo` with the previously saved `ls` result.

Comment: @SantoshA And it is. That's the last line of the output.

Comment: In other words, `make` processes all of its own expansions in the recipe before it actually executes the recipe. The last line of the recipe effectively becomes `@echo "lrwxrwxrwx ... /tmp/symlink -> old"`, and *then* all three lines (staring with the creation of the new symlink) of the recipe are executed.